# How to dynamically add options to a select element in an Angular component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-select

I currently have an Angular component that contains a solutions array that I want users to be able to manually alter. I already have a button that allows users to dynamically add to this array, but I'm trying to implement deletion. I want a select box to be displayed that contains all of the solutions, then when the user clicks one of the options and hits "delete solution", it will remove that element from the array.

Currently the html of my component looks as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="logged" class="solutionsInput">
          <div>
             New Solution:
             <div>
               <textarea id="Solution" [(ngModel)]="newSolution" placeholder="None"></textarea>
             </div>
         </div>
         <button class="add-solutions" (click)="addSolutions(defect)">
             Add Solution
          </button>
<!-- BELOW IS THE PART THAT NEEDS TO BE FIXED -->
          <select id = "solutions"></select>
          <button class="delete-solutions" (click)="deleteSolutions(defect)">
            Delete Solution
         </button>

      </div>
```

The typescript of my component looks as follows:

```
defect.solutions = [] //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ALTER
newSolution = "";
addSolutions(defect: Defect): void {
    if(this.newSolution !== "") {
      this.defectService.getSolutionsHelper(defect).subscribe((currSolutions) => {
        //not necessary to see all of this
        })
      });
    }
  }

deleteSolutions(defect: Defect): void {
   //THIS NEEDS TO BE IMLPEMENTED
}
```

Are there any ideas for what I should do? Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: I suggest using `*ngFor` to create the list of `option` elements from the array. Then you can simply use `splice` to remove the element from the array and your UI will update automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run into these situations, I use a multiselect drop down list. My team uses the Kendo UI for Angular pack, but there are other free choices, like this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

With this approach, you can simply bind your results from the call to this.defectService.getSolutionsHelper to the control (defect.solutions), and then the user can delete individual members from easily selectable items. Since the control is bound to defect.solutions, the control will natively trim the array.

This may work for you. Good luck!